# спарсить json данные

Tags: javascript, python

Имеется вот такой вид json. Нужно спарсить каждый "description"

```json
{
    "orders": [{
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "canSendReceipt": true,
        "receiptId": "9cd5f01fd3ed41a384faf04f28e79fb0",
        "orderId": "F2102211351463616",
        "createdAtMillis": 1613915506904,
        "updatedAtMillis": 1613915812732,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": 0,
        "presentmentAmount": "€0.00",
        "items": [{
            "description": "Rage 2",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerName": "Bethesda Softworks LLC",
            "amount": "€0.00",
            "price": 0,
            "offerId": "26c8bec5ae4f44b6b942b9564e81cafc",
            "namespace": "2736ab9fec9c4a93a7a2872ed5154d4b"
        }],
        "merchantGroup": "EGS_MKT"
    }, {
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "canSendReceipt": true,
        "receiptId": "f2131f08c7b84846a20b24b3c7b2c0cd",
        "orderId": "F2102211351122654",
        "createdAtMillis": 1613915472074,
        "updatedAtMillis": 1613915781238,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": 0,
        "presentmentAmount": "€0.00",
        "items": [{
            "description": "Absolute Drift",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerName": "Funselektor Labs INC",
            "amount": "€0.00",
            "price": 0,
            "offerId": "0c90d229f27a4251beee8b4776a8fb44",
            "namespace": "9d2f484bbec64aa8ad234b3199dcaf1c"
        }],
        "merchantGroup": "EGS_MKT"
    }, {
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "canSendReceipt": true,
        "receiptId": "352482c2e2154a9b9fdcc88844ef0c97",
        "orderId": "F2101161925140636",
        "createdAtMillis": 1610825114658,
        "updatedAtMillis": 1610825430967,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": 0,
        "presentmentAmount": "€0.00",
        "items": [{
            "description": "STAR WARS™ Battlefront™ II: Celebration Edition",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerName": "Electronic Arts",
            "amount": "€0.00",
            "price": 0,
            "offerId": "ea7721c6c2694e72813d3661bc68a2cb",
            "namespace": "b156c3365a5b4cb9a01a5e1108b4e3f4"
        }],
        "merchantGroup": "EGS_MKT"
    }, {
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "canSendReceipt": true,
        "receiptId": "8ade8367038f466680ac409314558f18",
        "orderId": "F2012230623264687",
        "createdAtMillis": 1608704606373,
        "updatedAtMillis": 1608704924545,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": 0,
        "presentmentAmount": "€0.00",
        "items": [{
            "description": "Metro: 2033 Redux",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerName": "Koch Media",
            "amount": "€0.00",
            "price": 0,
            "offerId": "0dfa5a4398bb44c8b1ac34e5f248fab9",
            "namespace": "petunia"
        }],
        "merchantGroup": "EGS_MKT"
    }, {
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "canSendReceipt": true,
        "receiptId": "8aa6235d14074563888b7f5f42d5ba36",
        "orderId": "F2012180536511836",
        "createdAtMillis": 1608269811295,
        "updatedAtMillis": 1608270144128,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": 0,
        "presentmentAmount": "€0.00",
        "items": [{
            "description": "Cities: Skylines",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerName": "Paradox Interactive",
            "amount": "€0.00",
            "price": 0,
            "offerId": "bf83aee67dd1475fb6bf2c8563f14b70",
            "namespace": "6009be9994c2409099588cde6f3a5ed0"
        }],
        "merchantGroup": "EGS_MKT"
    }, {
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "canSendReceipt": true,
        "receiptId": "54f46a5a8a5d40fe8aa52a96da3b6ee3",
        "orderId": "F2012020608280986",
        "createdAtMillis": 1606889308864,
        "updatedAtMillis": 1606889627698,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": 0,
        "presentmentAmount": "€0.00",
        "items": [{
            "description": "MudRunner",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerName": "Focus Home",
            "amount": "€0.00",
            "price": 0,
            "offerId": "7aea960be7dd4d86a9b30cf5daa03eeb",
            "namespace": "6bff1c13a8884b518bd44acaf691ddba"
        }],
        "merchantGroup": "EGS_MKT"
    }, {
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "canSendReceipt": true,
        "receiptId": "b321270fbcf34ca8ad41146adad32d14",
        "orderId": "A2011161441388942",
        "createdAtMillis": 1605537698556,
        "updatedAtMillis": 1605537778444,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": 799,
        "presentmentAmount": "€7.99",
        "items": [{
            "description": "1,000 V-Bucks",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerName": "Epic Games",
            "amount": "€7.99",
            "price": 799,
            "offerId": "ede05b3c97e9475a8d9be91da65750f0",
            "namespace": "fn"
        }],
        "merchantGroup": "FN_MKT"
    }, {
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "canSendReceipt": false,
        "receiptId": null,
        "orderId": "F2011101619334264",
        "createdAtMillis": 1605025173158,
        "updatedAtMillis": 1605025173229,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": 0,
        "presentmentAmount": "€0.00",
        "items": [{
            "description": "Throwback Axe",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerName": "Epic Games",
            "amount": "€0.00",
            "price": 0,
            "offerId": "4a238a27ef134a60bbaf2fbccb5bfad0",
            "namespace": "fn"
        }],
        "merchantGroup": "FN_MKT"
    }, {
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "canSendReceipt": false,
        "receiptId": null,
        "orderId": "F2009241523041436",
        "createdAtMillis": 1600960984697,
        "updatedAtMillis": 1600960984767,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": 0,
        "presentmentAmount": "€0.00",
        "items": [{
            "description": "Rocket League®",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerName": "Psyonix LLC",
            "amount": "€0.00",
            "price": 0,
            "offerId": "02d44be4c21c4ce094c6151133c91482",
            "namespace": "9773aa1aa54f4f7b80e44bef04986cea"
        }],
        "merchantGroup": "EGS_MKT"
    }, {
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "canSendReceipt": true,
        "receiptId": "2f0e7924d6fe429488c6fdd7e5c18327",
        "orderId": "F2009221625553636",
        "createdAtMillis": 1600791955220,
        "updatedAtMillis": 1600792258377,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "price": 0,
        "presentmentAmount": "€0.00",
        "items": [{
            "description": "Watch Dogs 2",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sellerName": "Ubisoft Entertainment",
            "amount": "€0.00",
            "price": 0,
            "offerId": "60d05e5e3a154257a22d6d49810b4b89",
            "namespace": "angelonia"
        }],
        "merchantGroup": "EGS_MKT"
    }],
    "count": 10,
    "start": 0,
    "total": 42
}
```

Пытаюсь спарсить вот так:

```py
r = request.get(html)
data = json.loads(r.text)
disc = data['orders']['items']['description']
print(disc)
```

Ну и собственно не парсит.
Получаю такую ошибку `indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/):

```
from dpath import util as dpu  # pip install dpath

r = request.get(html)
data = r.json()
res = dpu.values(data, "**/description")
```

результат:

```
In [273]: res
Out[273]:
['Rage 2',
 'Absolute Drift',
 'STAR WARS™ Battlefront™ II: Celebration Edition',
 'Metro: 2033 Redux',
 'Cities: Skylines',
 'MudRunner',
 '1,000 V-Bucks',
 'Throwback Axe',
 'Rocket League®',
 'Watch Dogs 2']
```